# Numpy Record Matrix: Sum only one field of all columns in record matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy record matrix. I initialized each row in it with this line:

```
r = np.recarray((len(list)), dtype=[('x', int), ('y', int), ('value', int)])
```

I then used vstack to stack rows to make a matrix:

```
supermatrix = np.vstack((supermatrix, r))
```

This eventually gives me a matrix:

```
[[(0, 0, 0) (1, 0, 1) (2, 0, 0) ..., (34, 34, 0) (35, 34, 1) (35, 35, 0)]
 [(0, 0, 0) (1, 0, 1) (2, 0, 1) ..., (34, 34, 0) (35, 34, 1) (35, 35, 0)]
 [(0, 0, 0) (1, 0, 1) (2, 0, 0) ..., (34, 34, 0) (35, 34, 1) (35, 35, 0)]
 ..., 
 [(0, 0, 0) (1, 0, 1) (2, 0, 1) ..., (34, 34, 0) (35, 34, 1) (35, 35, 0)]
 [(0, 0, 0) (1, 0, 1) (2, 0, 0) ..., (34, 34, 0) (35, 34, 1) (35, 35, 0)]
 [(0, 0, 0) (1, 0, 1) (2, 0, 1) ..., (34, 34, 0) (35, 34, 1) (35, 35, 0)]]
```

I want to sum only one of the elements' fields in each column.

I know that numpy has a `np.sums(axis=1)` method for use on normal numpy matrices, but I can't figure out how to get it to sum just one field.

How can this be done?

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: I want the sums to be in a list -- like if you were to use the np.sums(axis=1) method on a normal numpy matrix. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Can you add whole of your code to question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
In [87]: r = np.ones((10,), dtype=[('x', int), ('y', int), ('value', int)])

In [88]: s=np.vstack((r,r,r,r))

In [89]: s
Out[89]: 
array([[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1),
        (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1)],
       [(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1),
        (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1)],
       [(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1),
        (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1)],
       [(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1),
        (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1)]], 
      dtype=[('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<i4'), ('value', '<i4')])

In [90]: s['x']
Out[90]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

In [91]: s['x'].sum(axis=1)
Out[91]: array([10, 10, 10, 10])
```

`s['x']` gives you a 2d array with just the values from the 'x' field.  You can apply normal array operations to that.

Comment: That's exactly it! Wow, I actually got that array and didn't think to just do operations on it. Thanks!